# Fechamento automatico de aspas simples e duplas vscode

Tags: osx, visual-studio-code

Meu vscode não fecha automaticamente as aspas simples e duplas. Eu já desativei todas as extensões, o autoclosing já esta True, mas o problema ainda persiste.

> vscodeVersion 1.15.0 (1.15.0)
>
> MAC osx: Version 10.12.6 (16G29)
>
> "editor." autoClosingBrackets ": true,

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, o VSCode não detecta a aspa simples como caractére de abertura quando o idioma do teclado do Mac está configurado como Brasil - Pro.

A solução é alterar o idioma para Brasil ou U.S. através dos seguintes passos:

1. Em Preferências do Sistema > Teclado, clique no símbolo de adição (+) no canto esquerdo inferior
2. Escolha o idioma de sua preferência (English > U.S. ou Portuguese > Brasil)
3. Clique em "Adicionar".

Agora, no canto direito da barra de status, clique na bandeira do Brasil, e altere o idioma do teclado para o idioma selecionado no passo anterior.

---

É válido ressaltar que, tanto no idioma U.S. quanto no idioma Brasil, os acentos são inseridos de forma diferente, sendo que, para utilizá-los, basta acionar os seguintes atalhos:

- `´` - ⌥ + e
- `^` - ⌥ + i
- `˜` - ⌥ + n

Pressione a combinação necessária ao acento desejado e, em seguida, a letra que deseja acentuar